# Problems with TestFlightApp

Tags: objective-c, ios, testflight

I'm developing iOS apps and I'd like to share my apps with TestFlight testers. This is not the problem and works fine (via email). However, when I'm uploading a new build, I'd like to have in-app updates.

The SDK describes this as being possible, but I don't see anything from an update in my app.
I closed the app from "Multitasking".

I added the SDK to my project and in the AppDelegate my TeamToken, Checkpoints, etc. work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work out of the box with testflight, as I use it and have seen it work myself. Have you installed the app via testflight, opened, ran, submitted another build then re-opened the app?

Comment: It sounds pretty strange, if you are able to see checkpoints etc. Do you remember to update the build/version number when you upload new builds?

Comment: Hey all, yes, I updatet build/version number. @shawnwall, yes installed the app with testflight (from url, works fine) but in-app update not ... thank

Answer (score 1):

On testflight, have you enabled the force upgrade? (Your Application -> Build -> Build information -> Forced upgrades)

Also please make sure that the activity report is showing your session when you start your app.